# Is this right conversion from Swift to Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In swift

```
!tempPlays.values.contains(1)
```

In Objective C

```
(![[tempPlays objectForKey:@"1"] integerValue]) // tempPlays is NSDictionary
```

Help in this also ?

**IN SWIFT**

```
 button0.setTitle(plays[0] == 0 ? "O": (plays[0] == 1 ? "X" : button0.titleLabel!.text!), forState: UIControlState.Normal)`
```

**IN OBJECTIVE C**

```
 [_btn0 setTitle:([[playDictionary objectForKey:@"0"]integerValue] == 0 ? @"O" : ([[playDictionary objectForKey:@"0"]integerValue] == 1 ? @"X" : _btn0.titleLabel.text)) forState:UIControlStateNormal];`
```

New to iOS..

Comment: Please  ask the question clearly

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C

```
 if (![tempPlays.allValues containsObject:@"1"]) {}
```

or

```
if (![tempPlays.allValues containsObject:@(1)]) {}
```

for your added case

```
NSString *titleBtn = _btn0.titleLabel.text;
if ([playDictionary[@"0"] integerValue] == 0) {
     titleBtn = @"0";
}
else if ([playDictionary[@"1"] integerValue] == 1){
   titleBtn = @"X";
}
[_btn0 setTitle:titleBtn forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: tempPlays is NSDIctionary .values is not a property of it !

Comment: Help in this also   ???                            button0.setTitle(plays[0] == 0 ? "O": (plays[0] == 1 ? "X" : button0.titleLabel!.text!), forState: UIControlState.Normal)       IN SWIFT                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[_btn0 setTitle:([[playDictionary objectForKey:@"0"]integerValue] == 0 ? @"O" : ([[playDictionary objectForKey:@"0"]integerValue] == 1 ? @"X" : _btn0.titleLabel.text)) forState:UIControlStateNormal];   IN OBJECTIVE C

Comment: Add new answer or update this please, your code is absolutely unreadable

Comment: changed the above comment to answer